# Using If Statement to set behavior of a batch file based on ping statistics

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, ping

I'm writing a script to test multiple ethernet ports.  I've gotten everything down except for the if statement.

The batch file will call another batch file to disable one LAN and enable another, and then call another batch file to ping the default gateway.  I need the ping batch file to recognize the packet loss percentage, and behave accordingly.  More specifically, if the packet loss percentage is less than or equal to 10%, the ping batch file will close, and let the main batch file continue.  If the packet loss percentage is greater than 10%, I need the batch file to send a message "Test Failed" to the user.

Is this possible?

Thank You

Chris

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set gw=your gateway
for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in (
  'ping %gw%^|Find /i "Lost"'
  ) do (for /f "tokens=1" %%b in ("%%a") do (
   set num=%%b & set num=!num:%%=! 
   if !num! GTR 10 (Echo Test Failed) ELSE exit /b 0
  )
)
```